# Algoritmo Pseint sobre separar una cadena y sumar los números

Tags: string, bucles, algoritmos, pseint, pseudocódigo

Este es mi primera vez aquí en StackOverflow y de verdad que estoy desesperado.

Resulta que me piden un algoritmo en **Pseint**, donde un usuario debe introducir una cadena, pero esta cadena debe estar compuesta por números, un "-" o un " " (espacio). Ahora el detalle es que debo separar estos caracteres para luego sumar los números, donde el "-" indica resta y el " " espacio una suma. Un ejemplo seria:

`"23 45-4 -56" <-- cadena`
`23+45-4-56 <---convertirla internamente a operación`
`8 <--- resultado`

Pueden haber incluso espacios y - juntos, al final o al inicio, eso es lo que me confunde.

Hasta el momento esto es lo que he hecho:
He desarrollado un ciclo que recorra la cadena, y al momento de detectar un numero este lo encadena, pero si es un " " (espacio) o un "-", entonces habrá otro ciclo, pero que recorra las siguientes posiciones donde haya un " " o un "-" y determinar cuantos de ellos hay hasta encontrar de nuevo un numero y así sucesivamente

**PSeint**

```
Definir n,list,actual,group,carac Como Caracter
    Definir i,j,k,m,size,pos,sum,total,sum_rest Como Entero
    Escribir ""
    Escribir "Digite los números que desea sumar y separelos con un espacio en blanco:"
    Leer n
    size<-longitud(n)
    
    //Cantidad de espacios y -
    k<-0
    m<-0
    total<-0
    Para i<-0 Hasta size-1 Con Paso 1 Hacer
        Si Subcadena(n,i,i) = "0" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "1" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "2" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "3" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "4" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "5" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "6" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "7" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "8" o Subcadena(n,i,i) = "9" entonces 
            group<-group+subcadena(n,i,i)
        SiNo
            group<-""
            //si llegamos aqui es porque estamos en la posicion de un - o " "
            pos<-i
            Mientras pos<size-1 Hacer
                
                Si Subcadena(n,pos,pos) = " " o subcadena(n,pos,pos)="-"
                    carac<-Subcadena(n,i,i)
                    si carac=" " Entonces
                        k<-k+1
                    FinSi
                    
                    si carac="-" entonces 
                        m<-m+1
                    FinSi
                    
                    pos<-pos+1
                    
                SiNo
                    pos<-size-1
                FinSi
            Fin Mientras
            i<-pos
            
        FinSi
        
        
        sum<-ConvertirANumero(group)
        
        Si k>=1 o k<>m Entonces
        total<-total+(-1*sum)
        SiNo
        total<-total+(1*sum)
        FinSi
        
    Fin Para
    escribir "El total es de"
    escribir total
```

Y al momento de realizar las suma, me da resultados incorrectos y muy exagerados, por ejemplo si quiero sumar 13 + 3 me da 19 o resultados similares, especialmente con números grandes.

Me gustaría saber que es lo que está mal y no logro verlo o si podrían brindarme una solución para mejorar mi código. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Entiendo, seguiré las recomendaciones

Answer (score 0):

como va?? estuve viendo tu código y me sirvió para darme cuenta de algunas cosas que no me salían...
En primer lugar, no te toma el 13 porque no lo tienes definido en el if, sólo tienes números de 1 dígito del 1 hasta el 9. Debieras definir una lista de números más larga (hasta el 20 por ejemplo) para que te tome más valores.
Luego, si quieres tomar valores de 2 dígitos por separado tendrías más problemas, porque debes redefinir los valores del if para que cuando quieras sumar 18, NO te tome primero el 1 y luego el 8, por eso te recomiendo que redefinas desde el condicional los valores de a pares, ej: del "01" hasta "09", para agarrar del array los números correctos. Si vas a guardar éstos valores de a pares en un array, no olvides modificar la dimensión del mismo, ya que de lo contrario te saltará el mensaje de fuera de índice.
Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo quedaría el condicional tomando valores de a pares: desde el 01 hasta el 10.

`Si Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "00" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "01" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "02" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "03" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "04" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "05" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "06" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "07" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "08" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "09" o Subcadena(n,i,i+1) = "10" entonces  group<-group+subcadena(n,i,i+1)`

Ojalá te sirva!! saludos!!